# command line remove read only flag on all subfolder entries or overwrite read only files with robocopy

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, robocopy

I need one of two things to work:

1. I use ***robocopy*** to copy all sub-files and sub-folders from one folder to another, and the destination contains older files + files not in the source, and I need the files from the source to overwrite destination if present. The problem with this approach is read-only files.

   ```
   robocopy .... /E /NP /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /IA:R /IA:A /A-:R
   ```
2. I might use the windows command ***attrib*** but that does not remove the read-only flag for sub-files.

   ```
   attrib -r <path-to-folder> /S /D
   ```

   I might use it without the last two arguments as well.

Note: UAC is completely disabled and I am the owner of the files.

I cannot use *xcopy* as that does not work in bjam for me, and I don't have all the paths for all the files: I only have parent source folder and parent destination folder. The hierarchy must remain.

Comment: Did you try the `attrib` command line on the source, the destination or even both?